# Solution doesn't solve equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm using `Solve[LHS[y]==RHS, y]` to generate a solution ruleset, and yet when I apply these rulesets to `LHS` I'm not getting `RHS`.

Let me be a little clearer. Sorry that the expressions are so large, but I haven't been able to reproduce this with a simpler set of equations.

`justSin` is some function of `x` and `y`. `sinOfArcTan` is the same expression but with the substitution `y=ArcTan[y2]`.

```
justSin = 
 1/2 ((2 Sin[y] Sinh[2 x])  /
      (Cosh[2 x] + Cos[y] Sinh[2 x])  )  ^2

sinOfArctan = 
 1/2 ((2 Sin@ArcTan[y2] Sinh[2 x])  /
      (Cosh[2 x] + Cos@ArcTan[y2] Sinh[2 x])  )   ^2
```

Now I want to solve the following equation:

```
rhs = 2 Sinh[2 x]^2 
justSinSol     = FullSimplify@Solve[justSin == rhs, y]
sinOfArctanSol = FullSimplify@Solve[sinOfArctan == rhs, y2]
```

I get some rules out, the first one's a little complicated but the second is just

```
{{y2 -> -Csch[2 x]}, {y2 -> Csch[2 x]}}
```

Now I apply these rules to the original expression:

```
applyJS = Table[justSin /. justSinSol[[i]], {i, Length[justSinSol]}]
         // FullSimplify // Normal

applySA = Table[sinOfArctan /. sinOfArctanSol[[i]], {i, Length[sinOfArctanSol]}]
        // FullSimplify // Normal
```

While `applyJS` gives an answer equivalent to `rhs`, `applySA` does not.

```
(applyJS - rhs) // FullSimplify   (* --> {0,0,0,0}  *)
(applySA - rhs) // FullSimplify   (* --> not zero   *)
```

I have no idea why this could be the case. I could imagine the introduction of the substitution removing solutions, but I can't see why Mathematica would return a solution which doesn't (seem to) solve the equation.

---

EDIT:
As @Feyre points out, the solution *is* valid, but only for `x<0`. Why then does Mathematica not return a conditional?

Comment: I think adding the example which works just complicates the question. A minimal working example is best.

Comment: I agree that the example is pretty hefty, but I haven't found a more minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

> `Solve` uses non-equivalent transformations to find solutions of transcendental equations and hence it may not find some solutions and may not establish exact conditions on the validity of the solutions found.
>   ...
>   With `Method -> Reduce`, `Solve` uses only equivalent transformations and finds all solutions.

If we follow the guidance given in the docs, we get valid solutions.  The condition returned by `Solve` can be simplified for real `x`, if desired, as shown below.

```
sol = FullSimplify@Solve[sinOfArctan == rhs, y2, Method -> Reduce]

realsol = % // FullSimplify[#, 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. e_Equal :> Reduce[e, x, Reals] &}] &
```

> `Solve::useq`: The answer found by `Solve` contains equational condition(s).... A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions.

```
(*
  {{y2 -> ConditionalExpression[-Csch[2 x], Coth[2 x] + Sqrt[Coth[2 x]^2] == 0]},
   {y2 -> ConditionalExpression[Csch[2 x], Coth[2 x] + Sqrt[Coth[2 x]^2] == 0]},
   {y2 -> ConditionalExpression[-Csch[2 x], Coth[2 x] + Sqrt[Coth[2 x]^2] == 0]},
   {y2 -> ConditionalExpression[Csch[2 x], Coth[2 x] + Sqrt[Coth[2 x]^2] == 0]}}

  {{y2 -> ConditionalExpression[-Csch[2 x], x < 0]},
   {y2 -> ConditionalExpression[Csch[2 x], x < 0]},
   {y2 -> ConditionalExpression[-Csch[2 x], x < 0]},
   {y2 -> ConditionalExpression[Csch[2 x], x < 0]}}
*)
```

The real solutions are easier to check than the complex ones, because of the condition.

```
sinOfArctan == rhs /. realsol // Simplify
sinOfArctan == rhs /. realsol // Simplify[#, x < 0] &
(*
  {ConditionalExpression[True, x < 0],  ConditionalExpression[True, x < 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[True, x < 0],  ConditionalExpression[True, x < 0]}

  {True, True, True, True}
*)

SeedRandom[1];
sinOfArctan - rhs /. sol /. x -> # & /@ 
  RandomComplex[{-2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 5, WorkingPrecision -> 16] // N
(*
  {{Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, Undefined},
   {0.` + 0.` I, 0.` + 0.` I, 0.` + 0.` I, 0.` + 0.` I},
   {Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, Undefined},
   {0.` + 0.` I, 0.` + 0.` I, 0.` + 0.` I, 0.` + 0.` I},
   {Undefined, Undefined, Undefined, Undefined}}
*)
```

So I guess it's not a bug, but a documented limitation of the default method in `Solve`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is valid, for $x<0$

```
Simplify[(sinOfArctan /. sinOfArctanSol[[2]]) == rhs, 
 Assumptions -> x < 0]
```

> True

```
Plot[sinOfArctan /. sinOfArctanSol, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
Plot[rhs, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]
[image]

Note that if we use

```
sinOfArctanSol = Reduce[sinOfArctan == rhs, y2];
```

And then run

```
Simplify[sinOfArctanSol, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

> False

This suggests there is no solution possible for $x\ge0$

I suspect this has to do with trying to fit odd functions into an even function.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Shouldn't sinOfArctanSol be a conditional expression in that case, explicitly requiring x>=0? It seems strange that `FullSimplify[applySA - rhs, x > 0]` gives `-2 Sinh[2 x]^2 Tanh[4 x]^2`, rather than some kind of error.

Comment: @Gyppo one would think so, could be a bug.